# How do I get count of events for each city

Tags: mysql

events table has a column called "city_id" . I would like to see the result like this

```
Miami 30
Tampa 11
San Franciso 29
```

I am using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN, GROUP BY, COUNT... That's most likely all you need to make this simple query!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help you

```
SELECT 
  city_id,
  max(city_name),
  count(*)
FROM events
GROUP BY
  city_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had city name in another table

```
select e.city_id, c.name, count(*) eventcount
from events e
join city c on c.id = e.city_id
group by e.city_id, c.name
```

Comment: +1, I don't see anything wrong with your solution, on the contrary, is the only answer that assumes that the city name is on another table. Why was downvoted?